# Problems baking multiple materials into one texture

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, texture-baking, baking

I have two materials that I'm trying to bake into one texture. I have the same image texture node selected on each material, but when I bake it, only one material shows up.

First material with image texture node:
[image: Pebbles material node]

Second material with the same image texture node selected:
[image: Ground material node]

Here's the bake result. Only the second material shows up.
[image: Bake result]

[EDIT]

Result of unwrapping with Smart UV Project:
[image]

I'm looking for something like this where the materials overlap in a way consistent with how they appear on the plane. I had to save two separate diffuse textures for the pebbles and the ground then combine them in Photoshop, but I was hoping there was a way to save this in Blender to avoid those extra steps.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You unwrap is bad, it makes your faces overlapping in the *UV Editor* and therefore the bakings are overlapping as well, you need to unwrap again, for example with the *Smart UV Project* mode, and it will work fine.

Here is what it gives if I unwrap with the *Smart UV Project* mode and if I use the image you show, as you see it works perfectly:

[image]

Comment: I edited my question with the result of this. Still doesn't look right. I'm trying to bake the materials together so that they are overlapping appropriately and will look like my plane in the viewport.

Comment: Hello, why do you say that it doesn't look right, it works fine for me, see my edit

Comment: See my edits in my question. Basically I'm trying to see if there's a way to have the ground texture underneath the pebbles texture, so you can see it where there's transparency in the pebbles texture. When I do the Smart UV Project mode and try to apply that texture to a new plane, it doesn't look like my original. The ground and pebbles textures are separated.

Comment: I don't understand, I hope someone will